# Wrong mesh locating after application startup (only window resize fix this)

Tags: opengl, glfw

Most likely this is not a problem, but a feature of the configuration of the window before its creation, but I have the following problem. Immediately after I launch my application, my model is displaced and stretched out, but it immediately snaps into place as soon as I start resizing the window.
I wrote following callback on window resize:

```
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int w, int h) {
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w <= h)
       glOrtho (-1.5, 1.5, -1.5*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w,
          1.5*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, -10.0, 10.0);
    else
       glOrtho (-1.5*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h,
          1.5*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, -1.5, 1.5, -10.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Right after GLFW application start:
[image: Right after GLFW application start]

Window been slightly resized:
[image: Window been slightly resized]

I didn't have similar issues with GLUT...

Comment: If anyone interested in full code: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1767

Comment: I can't see where you set your ```GL_PROJECTION``` except from your resize function. You should probably also do that on program startup

Comment: @Thrasher, I added glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); (and even copy full display callback code in rendering loop with w=800 and h=600 fixed values) but nothing changed. I'am newbie in OpenGL so my be I misunderstand you.

Comment: I'm sorry. But no time to review your code in detail. But i'm pretty sure your posted code is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SCALE_TO_MONITOR, GLFW_TRUE)` for correct window size on Retina High DPI display, but to call `glViewport()` I passes old unscaled width and height. The solution is fetch the current framebuffer size with `glfwGetFramebufferSize()` and pass those dimensions to `glViewport()` instead and it should render correctly.